# Websocket- Client recive byte array

Tags: c#, websocket

I want to create a webocket to cominicate between client and server. I download sourcecode from  https://github.com/magoswiat/WebSocketsDemo . It is very useful to me. But I want to send and receive by byte array not string.
I find overload menthods, but I still not find the way to recive byte array in client. Others are OK
In code we set receive event.

```
websocketClient.MessageReceived     += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(websocketClient_MessageReceived);
```

and implement:

```
 private void websocketClient_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Message Received. Server answered: " + e.Message);


        }
```

How to change e (MessageReceivedEventArgs). To get byte array

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx)? That's how you get a byte array out of a C# string. Mind the encoding, but UTF8 should cover most cases.

Comment: Thanks. I know that. But the server make by the other one. My turn is on client. And Server send byte array so I must receive byte array, not string.

Comment: @TienTran, Sockets send bytes, not "strings". Bytes are bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I found out the way. Use DataReceived event instead of MessageReceived

Answer (score 0):

`MessageWebSocket` returns a `MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args` in `MessageReceived`, and this provides you with `args.GetDataStream()` where you can find the bytes.